# How to find first time visitors in Google Analytics on a daily basis

Tags: google-analytics

This might be a very silly questions but for all the detailed analytics that Google provides - I'm just looking to find the daily first time visitors on my website.

And I'm not able to get that information.

When I select the date range say "yesterday" - I get the following information

Sessions - 1200
Users - 1000

New Users - 77%
Returning - 23%

But the "New User" is defined for that date range - which means in my case if a user visited last week and comes again yesterday - for yesterday's analytic's he will be considered new - because for that date range - its the first time he has come.

What I'm looking for is absolute first time visitors on my site on a daily basis.

Is there anyway to get this data in Google Analytics - if not is there any other tool that provides this data.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that "New Users" refers only to that date range. The definition for the [`ga:newUsers`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_newusers) metric is as follows:

> The number of users whose session on your property was marked as a first-time session.

And the definition of the [`ga:userType`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_usertype) dimensions is:

> A boolean indicating if a user is new or returning. Possible values: New Visitor, Returning Visitor

So, to answer your question, you can use these dimensions and metrics to limit your query to only those users who, for them, this is their first visit to your site (ever).

For example, this query will show you what pages are being viewed by only new users for a particular date (or date range):

[https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A42124519&dimensions=ga%3Apagepath&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3AuserType%3D%3DNew%20Visitor&start-date=2014-12-02&end-date=2014-12-02&max-results=50](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Apagepath&metrics=ga%253Apageviews&filters=ga%253AuserType%253D%253DNew%2520Visitor&start-date=2014-12-02&end-date=2014-12-02&max-results=50)

Comment: Thanks Philip for your insights and the link to query explorer - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I never looked at the new users being only defined for that date range.  But using that idea, couldn't you look at the dates from site conception to today and go to Audience -> Custom -> User defined, and look at the graph of new users?

I'll be interested in the follow up on this topic, because as I said I didn't think new users were only for the date range.